# How to use Google Civic API through multiple addresses using Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to use Google's Civic API to run through a list of addresses to find the state representatives name and email address and place that data into a Google Sheet.

I've successfully made the call using one of the addresses, but is there a way to run the API call across multiple addresses and populate that into a new cell?

```
function findRep() {

  // Call the Google Civic API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address={address}&includeOffices=true&levels=administrativeArea1&roles=legislatorLowerBody&roles=legislatorUpperBody&fields=divisions%2CnormalizedInput%2Cofficials&key={mykey}");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  // Add to Google Sheet
  var fact = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue([fact]);
}
```

Comment: It seems that there are no methods for running the batch get and the batch request for Representatives: representativeInfoByAddress. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives/representativeInfoByAddress) So although I'm not sure about the number of addresses, how about using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` in the loop and/or using `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))

Comment: You might be able to leverage the API's batch request endpoint ([see discovery service listing for civic API](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/civicinfo/v2/rest) - search for the term "batch"). `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()` (as suggested by Tanaike) should work just as well.

Comment: I think that @Dimu Designs 's comment is a good information. If the batch requests can be used for your situation, it will be able to reduce not only the process cost, but also the quota of use of the API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! This is one of my first times working with APIs so I'm not super familiar with what's possible.

For using batch or `fetchAll` would I just append all the addresses into the URL?

Comment: Before I propose a sample script, can I ask you about the values you want? Can you provide the sample values you want using the retrieved value with your script? Of course, please remove your personal information. Although I thought that the name, email and place might be the value of `officials[0].name, officials[0].emails, officials[0].address`, I might misunderstand about `the state representatives name and email address and place`. About this, I have to apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Dimu Designs Unfortunately, although I tested to run the batch request for Civic Information API, it seems that in the current stage, the batch request cannot be used at this API. `404 Not Found` was returned. The endpoint I used is `https://www.googleapis.com/batch/civicinfo/v2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetchAll() function [1] to send all the requests you need in batch. I get the addresses array from the "Addresses" sheet and insert the results in the same Spreadsheet but in the "Results" sheet.

```
function findRep() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Results")
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Addresses")
  var addresses = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var requests = [];

  //Loop to set up the requests array
  for(var i=1; i<addresses.length; i++) {
    var address = addresses[i];
    var request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=' + address + '&includeOffices=true&levels=administrativeArea1&roles=legislatorLowerBody&roles=legislatorUpperBody&fields=divisions%2CnormalizedInput%2Cofficials&key=[API-KEY]';
    requests.push(request)    
  }

  //Get the responses in batch
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);

  //Iterate the responses object and insert the data  
  for(var i=0; i<responses.length; i++) {
    var response = JSON.parse(responses[i].getContentText());
    var official = response.officials[0].name;
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(official);
  }
}
```

In my code I only use the first value from the officials array and insert the name of that person. Because there's no email field for each official.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)